# searchTwitter() in twitteR package for R (2.15.2) - high number of duplicate tweets

Tags: r, twitter

Trying to create a dataframe of Twitter usernames associated with keyword through pulls from the Twitter REST API. But queries using `searchTwitter()` on many search terms (e.g. `#rstats`), even for large samples like `n = 1000`, return high degree (>90%) of duplicate tweets.

A specific example would be:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("#rstats", n = 1000)
tweets.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(tweets, as.data.frame))

df.undup <- df[duplicated(tweets.df) == FALSE,]
dim(df.undup)
```

I'm wondering if this is caused by limits on pagination if the search term is relatively scarce?

Comment: There was a bug fixed in the dev version which might resolve this. Give that a try (either via github or my site) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, should the 3rd line in your code be `df.undup <- tweets.df[duplicated(tweets.df) == FALSE,]` ?

I guess you're getting less than 1000 tweets, when you run the above code (I got 604, and the result of  `dim(df.undup)` is `604  10`). So the problem, I guess, is not that of duplicates being there, but that there are lesser number of tweets than 1000.

If you look at the created date, the oldest tweets are from 14th March (a week ago). Twitter API usuallly usually doesn't allow one to access tweets more than 7-9 days old. I guess that's why you're getting a lesser number of tweets.

To check, see if `dim(tweets.df)` and `dim(undup.df)` return the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! Line 3 should be `== FALSE` because `duplicated()` returns the logical `TRUE` if the observation is duplicated - I'm looking for non-duplicated rows. I always get `dim(tweets.df)` equivalent to my `n=` - did you get 604 as number of rows from `dim(df.undup)`? Thanks for the input about the date restriction - that would explain the >1000 results, but not (necessarily?) the duplicates.

Comment: Oops, meant <1000 results.

Comment: Right, that part is how I intended.