# searchTwitter( ) in R package for R 2.15.3. High number of duplicates

Tags: r, twitter, duplicates

Removing duplicates from the searchTwitter output works fine, the problem is that the amount of original tweets that the searchTwitter() function provides is always 100, no matter n=1000 or n=3000.

This is the code i've used:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("#rstats", n = 1000)
tweets.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(tweets, as.data.frame))

df.undup <- tweets.df[duplicated(tweets.df) == FALSE,] 
dim(df.undup)
```

The resulting data frame has always 100 rows, so that means the amount of original tweets is 100.

```
dim(df.undup)
tweets [1] 100 12
```

My question is: Does this have something to do with the twitter API and how could i get round this problem.

I'm using R version 2.15.3 on a Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: I've had a similar issue since the API cutover but didn't have time to debug, so I just switched to Python for the time being (very similar steps/process). I'm fairly certain it's API-related. (Using 2.15.3 on 10.8.3 btw). I think they fixed it in dev (take a look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548316/searchtwitter-in-twitter-package-for-r-2-15-2-high-number-of-duplicate-twe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to install the packages. Here is the code i've used just in case someone is interested. But the problem remains the same, the original tweets remain just 100.

I wonder why are we getting different results regarding duplicates.

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/ROAuth_0.9.4.tar.gz",
             repos=NULL,type="source",
             INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")

install.packages("~/Downloads/twitteR_1.1.5.tar.gz",
             repos=NULL,type="source",
             INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")

library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)

tweets <- searchTwitter("#rstats", n = 1000)
tweets.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(tweets, as.data.frame))

df.undup <- tweets.df[duplicated(tweets.df) == FALSE,]
dim(df.undup)

dim(df.undup)
[1] 100  12
```

Comment: Is this really the full code? Didn't you have to initialize ROAuth? Using this exact command: `searchTwitter("#rstats", n = 1000)` I got back 706 unique tweets (10AM EST).

Comment: I´ve done the ROAuth step, otherwise i wouldn´t be getting any results from the search. What version of R are you using, are you using OS x as well? It seems this might be making a difference.

Comment: R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01); Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit). I'll give it a shot on my mac later and report the results.

Comment: that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: The new version is out there and it works fine!       install.packages("~/Downloads/twitteR_1.1.5.tar.gz",
                 repos=NULL,type="source",
                 INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the presently available versions of the `twitteR` package aren't working properly. You can grab the most recent versions which appear to work better than those available on CRAN from Geoff Jentry's webpage.

http://geoffjentry.hexdump.org/twitteR_1.1.5.tar.gz

It requires ROAuth 0.9.4 (also not yet updated on CRAN)

http://geoffjentry.hexdump.org/ROAuth_0.9.4.tar.gz

I have a feeling you may have trouble getting it to work on MacOSX unless you can compile the packages (i.e. unless you do not require binary packages).

I am still getting dupes with these new versions, but not as many.